# Android customize created file name with MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage

Tags: android

in my application i'm trying to save bitmap with `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage` and i'm try to customize choose created file name with this method, but after pass any file name as String, this method create random file name and i can not change that, for example in this code i want to create `"123456"` and save it

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOut = null;
bitmapFileName = "123456";
File file = new File(path, bitmapFileName + ".jpg");
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();

drawView.getDrawingCache().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); 

String imgSaved = null;
imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
```

after save image this method create file name as `14524645878.jpg` and not `123456.jpg` whats problem? or how to find and get witch filename created by this mthod